# how to recursively call same code in same function each time

Tags: python, dictionary

I have code like this where `e` is one dict and `d` is one more dict.

```
e = { 'rrr':
        { 'prefix'    : 'inr',
          'reference' : 'Inr',
          'decimal'   : 0,
          'formula'   : 'a+h',
          'm'         : '',
        },
      'a' : 
        { 'prefix'    : 'inr',
          'reference' : 'Inr',
          'decimal'   : 0,
          'formula'   : 'b+c',
          'm'         : '',
        },
      'b' :
        { 'prefix'    : 'inr',
          'reference' : 'Inr',
          'decimal'   : 0,
          'formula'   : 'r+d',
          'm'         : 'm',
        },
      'h' :
        { 'prefix'    : 'inr',
          'reference' : 'Inr',
          'decimal'   : 0,
          'formula'   : 'b+y',
          'm'         : 'm',
        }
    }


d = { 'r':
        { 'prefix'    : 'inr',
          'reference' : 'Inr',
          'decimal'   : 0,
          'curyear'   : 1,
          'prevyear'  : 1,
        },
      'd' : 
        { 'prefix'    : 'inr',
          'reference' : 'Inr',
          'decimal'   : 0,
          'curyear'   : 2,
          'prevyear'  : 3,
        },
      'c' : 
        { 'prefix'    : 'inr',
          'reference' : 'Inr',
          'decimal'   : 0,
          'curyear'   : 4,
          'prevyear'  : 5,
        }
    }

for k,v in e.iteritems():
    a = re.findall('\w+', e[k]['formula'])
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        if not d.has_key(a[i]):
             if e.has_key(a[i]):
                 getValue2(e, a[i])
```

`getvalue2` is a recursive function like this

```
def getValue2(e, key):
    b = re.findall('\w+', e[key]['formaula'])
    if e.has_key(b[i]):
        getValue2(e, key)
    values = [d[x]['prevyear'] if x in d else 0 for x in a]
    values1 = [d[x]['curyear'] if x in d else 0 for x in a]
    x2 = dict(zip(a, values))
    x3 = dict(zip(a, values1))
    d[k] = {
            'prefix'    : e[k]['prefix'],
            'reference' : e[k]['reference'],
            'decimal'   : e[k]['decimal'],
            'prevyear'  : eval(e[k]['formula'], x2),
            'curyear'   : eval(e[k]['formula'], x3),
           }
```

`e` dict has  `rrr` key and it has formula value `a+h` where `a` is one more key in dict `e` with formula value `b+c` and `b` is one more key in dict `e` with formula value `r+d`. And `r` and `d` values are in dict `d` and I need to append this `rrr`, `a`, `b` value to dict but values are not appending correctly, so I am using above recursive function.

In above function this code has to be called recursively

```
values = [d[x]['prevyear'] if x in d else 0 for x in a] # I am checking if k in d store that value else 0
values1 = [d[x]['curyear'] if x in d else 0 for x in a]
x2 = dict(zip(b, values)) # I am creating dict of tag,values
x3 = dict(zip(b, values1))
d[k] = {
        'prefix'    : e[k]['prefix'],
        'reference' : e[k]['reference'],
        'decimal'   : e[k]['decimal'],
        'prevyear'  : eval(e[k]['formula'], x2),
        'curyear'   : eval(e[k]['formula'], x3),
       }
```

on this condition

```
b = re.findall('\w+', e[key]['formaula'])
if e.has_key(b[i]):
    getValue2(e, key)
```

But both codes are in single function but I am not getting how to use that code...

Comment: In the first code snippet, did you miss a quote for `rrr` in `e`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg now its correct. help me

Comment: off topic but... single letter variable names should be given to simple objects with limited scope and meaning.

Comment: you have to add `i` and `a` to the interface of `getValue2`, otherwise this will only work at top level (at it would be easier to read)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you wish to call some code recursively under a certain condition. Your code is not very clear to follow so I'm just going to give general advice. If you wish to compute a value under a condition but the computation itself needs to be done recursively then you should move the recursive code to a separate function. That separate function can then call itself recursively. For example:

```
def func1(a, b, c):
    func2(a, b, c)

def func2(a, b, c):
    # do computation here
    if condition:        
        func2(a2, b2, c2) # recursive call here
```

Note that you have to make sure that `func2` does not keep calling itself all the time. The recursion does have to end at some point (so `condition` needs to be `False` at some point but at least it's evaluated with every recursive call). You can also return values by using `return func2(a2, b2, c2)`.